Where to store large files in an electron desktop app
I have an electron app where users "upload" (everything is stored locally on the users computer) thousands or more textfiles. These may exceed a couple of Gb in total. These are then suppose to be processed and put into a sqlite database that may also exceed a Gb, this sqlite database will then be used repeatedly make complex queries in the app.
I would like to know where is most appropriate to store the database and text files (if an update requires reprocessing), when searching for an answer I came across mostly app.getPath('userData') that is used to store configuration data. But per the documentation https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetapppath it is not recommended for larger files because of backups. So then is it better to store it in something like app.getAppPath() or somewhere else?

i would still go for userData. As the name already describes, it is the place to store user specific data. You could use the Documents folder, but that is often synchronized with oneDrive etc, so too much data in there is a bad idea. And oneDrive can mess up all kind of apps when it stores the Document folder only online. I am not sure if electron is affected by that too, but probably yes.
This question is not electron specific, so you may wanna exclude electron when you try to search for a solution for this.
